# Overriding template files in own theme, loaded through JS (Knockout.js)

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

Since the official [Magento 2.0 forums](https://community.magento.com/t5/Theming-Layout-Design-Questions/Magento-2-Frontend-Developer-Documentation/m-p/10959#U10959) aren't of any help, i'll post my question here as well.

We're in the process of building our own theme based on the Magento Blank theme and we would like to implement 2 small changes to the minicart dropdown in the header. These files are loaded through JS (Knockout.js framework), but simply duplicating the file to our own theme in the same folder (`Name/name2/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`) and editing them doesn't show up any changes so we suspect the override behaviour is different in this case.

Can someone point us in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: We can use RequireJs to override the html templates. We can read more here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108788/how-to-override-template-files-for-magento2-extension/121702#121702

Answer (score 3):

This is the proper way to override the html file. I also had this issue, I think it's browser caching that prevents showing the changes. I do not have a real solution for this problem, but you can open the webshop in an incognito window each time you changed the .html file.

Answer (score 2):

This is proper way to override template file. You have to remove folder manually from `pub/static/frontend/{{Package}}/{{theme}}` folder and clear your browser cache.

Run command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Try load page and changes are display.

Thanks.