# how to override template files for magento2 extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, template

In magento2 to override template files [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html#theme-inherit-templates), but for magento2 extension we have to follow [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-file-structure.html).

So how to override template files in magento2 extension with out considering theme inheritance.

I want to override `vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\form\components\collection.js` and `vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\templates\form\components\collection.html` for customer address tab modifications.

With using theme inheritance i can do this by implementing above files in my custom theme files in **`Magento_Ui`** folder, but how could I achieve the same for magento2 extension i.e. with in `app/code/vendor/module` folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, we can override js and html template via requirejs config. In our module, we create `requirejs-config.js` under `view/frontend` or `view/adminhtml`. For example, in your case:

**app/code/{Vendor}/{Module_Name}/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection':
                'Vendor_ModuleName/js/form/components/collection',
            'Magento_Ui/templates/form/components/collection.html':
                'Vendor_ModuleName/template/form/components/collection.html'
        }
    }
};
```

We can find the path of js and html files under `pub/static`.

In our module, create our custom js and html template:

**app/code/{Vendor}/{Module_Name}/view/frontend/web/js/form/components/collection.js**
**app/code/{Vendor}/{Module_Name}/view/frontend/web/template/form/components/collection.html**

The most important thing is that after running static content deploy command, the js and html template files under `web/js` and `web/template` will be 'copied' to `pub/static`. For example, Magento Ui module:

[image]

Magento will get the js and html templates from `pub/static`. The all require config from `requirejs-config.js` will be also generated in `pub/static/_requirejs`. It handles the loading of js and html template files. So, requirejs helps us to override html template files.

Comment: ".js" is not needed and don't work, just 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection':
                'Vendor_ModuleName/js/form/components/collection'

Comment: There is a typo error that I can't edit myself: replace requirejs_config.js with requirejs-config.js Otherwise thank you very much for the info. Very useful for me

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh is it possible to override `.html` files? I am trying to override `Magento_SalesRule/template/payment/discount.html'` but with the above method is not working for me, do you have some idea on this?