# How do I extend Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data.js?

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, theme, requirejs

How do I extend `Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data.js` in a custom theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can override the js via RequireJs, in your module:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data':
            'Vendor_Module/js/checkout-data'
        }
    }
};
```

We can read more [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108788/how-to-override-template-files-for-magento2-extension/121702#121702).

Comment: That is not the answer the op asked how to extend not over ride it.

Comment: @JoelDavey that's an old answer. We should try with *mixins*.

Answer (score 2):

One way to extend it is like this

```
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, storage) {
    'use strict';


    return function (checkoutData) {

        var mixin = {

            myCustomFunction: function() {

            }

        };

        return $.extend(checkoutData, mixin);
    };
});
```

your require-config.js

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout-data-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```